# How to exclude META-INF folder from the custom jar file using maven-jar-plugin

Tags: java, maven, plugins, jar

I want to create a jar file named images.jar, which will contain only the png images which are fetched from the /images/ folder in the working directory.

I tried the following approach:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <addMavenDescriptor>false</addMavenDescriptor>
                </archive>
                <classifier>images</classifier>
                <classesDirectory>${project.basedir}/image</classesDirectory>
                <includes>**/*</includes>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

But this will create the jar file that includes all images and META-INF folder containing MANIFEST.MF file also.

I have found that the below line

```
<addMavenDescriptor>false</addMavenDescriptor>
```

is used to exclude META-INF/maven folder.

It does exclude pom and property file inside META-INF, but it doesn't exclude the MANIFEST.MF file.

What should be the correct approach?

Comment: You can try the maven assembly plugin..

Comment: A jar is a zip file with some meta information. Sounds like you could do with plain zip.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen and J Fabian, thanks for the input. I have found a solution and updated my question. Could you please go through it one more time?